# What variable type can hold 10^100?

Tags: vb.net, math, visual-studio-2012, int, long-integer

I need a variable to hold a number up to 10^100.  Will an Integer hold that or is their another variable type I should use?

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and VB.net

Comment: BigInteger: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx

Comment: Must be a duplicate: I'm sure a moderator would know...

Comment: https://www.google.com.au/search?hl=en&q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+&meta=#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=site:stackoverflow.com+.net+BigInteger&oq=site:stackoverflow.com+.net+BigInteger&gs_l=serp.3...4167.4900.1.5079.5.5.0.0.0.2.428.840.4-2.2.0...0.0...1c.1.9.psy-ab.a7xubKEqXYA&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.45175338,d.cGE&fp=c4404eb85f85c9cd&biw=1343&bih=898

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`BigInteger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx):

> Represents an arbitrarily large signed integer.